# How can I simplify boolean Algebra Expressions without using outside Java addons?

Tags: java, boolean, simplify

I am trying to take a Boolean algebra expression generated from another part of the project and simplify it before I output it. This Boolean expression will only include or statements due to the nature of the rest of the program.

An example would be starting with an expression like aC + bC + BC + Ab + Ac + AC + AB and ending with A + C. The lower case letters indicate not e.g. a means not A.

I have struggled for hours trying to figure this out, but every time I solve one case I ruin another. I imagine there is some recursive function for this problem but I struggled to find anything elsewhere.

Edit: To be clear, I understand how to simplify the expression on paper, I just am unable to simplify it using Java.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void mutate (ArrayList<String> Final, ArrayList<String> Factored, String a){
 int multiples = 0;
 String holder = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < Final.size(); i++){
 if (Final.get(i).contains(a)){
     multiples++;
     if (multiples == 1)
        holder = Final.get(i);
     if (multiples >=2)
         Factored.add(Final.get(i));
 }
 }
if (multiples > 1)
 Factored.add(holder);
 }
public static void simplify (ArrayList<String> Factored, char a, ArrayList<String> Main){
String temp = "";
int size = Factored.size();
int cnt = 0;
int cnt2 = 0;
int holder = 0;
System.out.println(Factored);
int menial = 0;

if (Factored.size() == 0)
menial = 1;
else{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){             //Gets rid of leading letters
    if(Factored.get(i).charAt(0) == a){
        temp = Factored.get(i).substring(1);
        Factored.add(temp);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){             //Gets rid of leading letters
    if(Factored.get(i).charAt(1) == a){
        temp = Factored.get(i).substring(1);
        Factored.add(temp);
    }
}   

for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){             
        Factored.remove(j - cnt);
        cnt++;
    }   
for (int i = 0; i < Factored.size(); i++){              //gets rid of duplicates if they exist
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Factored.size();j++)
        if (Factored.get(i).equals(Factored.get(j))){
            cnt2++;
            if (cnt2 == 1)
                holder = i;
        }

}
    if (cnt2 >= 1)
            Factored.remove(holder);    

    String temp1 = "";
    int size1 = Factored.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){      //Makes it uppercase
        temp1 = Factored.get(i).toUpperCase();
        Factored.add(temp1);
    }
    int cnt3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <size1; i++){
        Factored.remove(i-cnt3);
        cnt3++;
    }
    int sizeOver2 = Factored.size()/2;
    int holder1 = 0; int holder2 = 0;
    for (int q = 0; q < sizeOver2; q++){    
    int cnt4 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Factored.size(); i++){              //gets rid of duplicates if they exist now that there are caps
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Factored.size();j++)
        if (Factored.get(i).equals(Factored.get(j))){
            cnt4++;
            if (cnt4 == 1)
                holder1 = i;
                holder2 = j;
        }

        if (cnt4 >= 1){
            Factored.remove(holder1);
            Factored.remove(holder2 - 1);
        }

    }
    }
    if (Factored.size() == 0)
        Main.add(Character.toString(a));
    else if (Factored.size() > 1)
            menial = 5;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < Factored.size(); i++)
            Main.add(Factored.get(i));
}}

}
```

Edit2: I have added my code above. I apologize for the slopiness in advance, it got pretty messy towards the end. The Factored arraylist has all of the elements of the boolean expression separated E.g. the first element is aC, and the second is bC, etc. My plan was to find duplicates and try to factor them out, but after coding all of this I realized the egregious logic error. It has to be more complicated than that and at this point I'm lost in my own code.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you mean. Can you please go more into what you need help with? Maybe post your current code

Comment: How are you going about simplifying it on paper; by factoring it out manually or using a k-map?

Comment: Also I think it's much easier to understand to use more formal means of negating a symbol, such as `_a`, `a'`, or `'a`. It's more clear that it's a negation of a known symbol and not some other symbol. Perhaps it's just preference though.

Comment: ...and can you provide the code that you're currently using please?

Comment: Essentially I just cannot come up with a way to code a simplification such that the program will change any Boolean expression of only OR operations into its simplest form. On paper I am simplifying it by factoring it out manually, I have heard about k-maps but I am not familiar with them. I would also prefer to use a' but the assignment requires that the notation I previously mentioned be used. I am a high school AP Java student so I am a bit ignorant.

Comment: Let say you need to teach someone else to simplify **any** such expression.  Can you write down such instructions?

Comment: If people think it would be beneficial I could post the whole project, but essentially I take the input and wind up with a String ArrayList in which each element is one of the things being added e.g. aC or BC

Comment: Yes I could easily show someone on paper how to simplify an expression like the one above. You factor out the C from the first three elements and the A from the last four. This leaves you with C (a + b + B) + A(c + C + B) and then from there the b+B simplifies to 1 in the first factorization and in the second the b+B simplifies to 1 so you wind up with C + A

Comment: I don't know about posting the "whole" project but definitely the code that you're using to simplify so we can help you improve it as opposed to writing it for you. It'd be best if you could say which part of the process fails.

Comment: No, can you teach them how to simplify **an** expression, so it would work for **any** expression?

Comment: I think it would be easier to use kmaps..